# Apache port changed but still have to http://localhost:81/dashboard/

Tags: apache, xampp

I changed Apache port from 80 to 81 because 80 is used by skype.

> (I did this
>
> **Locate the following lines** :
>       #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
>
> Listen 80
>
> ServerName localhost:80
>
> **Replace them by** :
>       #Listen 12.34.56.78:81
>
> Listen 81
>
> ServerName localhost:81)

Long story short, if I do http://localhost:81/dashboard/ it works but I want to only use http://localhost/dashboard/.

I did Xampp -> Config -> Service and Port Settings -> Main port changed from 80 to 81 and SSL port still 443

I'd like to know where's the mistake and how can I repair it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open http://localhost/dashboard/ your apache should work on port 80, this is default http port.
So you have to open skype and go to Tools->Options->Advanced->Connection and uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections"

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP protocol is set to port 80 by the IANA standards.  If you want to use connect to an HTTP server on another port, you *must* add the port to the URI, as in http://localhost:81/

Now, you *can* edit /etc/services on a linux box and change 'http' to 81, but this is **not recommended**, as any other HTTP connections from that host to all servers will all try to connect to port 81, which will break all HTTP clients.  (Seriously, this will probably break all kinds of things you don't expect.  Just use the port in the URI.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change skype's default port as follow...

Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection and uncheck the box "**use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections**"

Anyway your apache must work on port 80 in order to access http://localhost/dashboard without mentioning a port.

Comment: @Vasary Great. Please mark my answer as the correct answer if it worked.